# jqplot image below plot curve

Tags: javascript, graph, gradient, jqplot

What I want is to get a rainbow gradient(VIBYOR) to appear in the area below curve of my plot.

I'm using jqPlot, and I'm wondering if there is a way to set it to use an image to render for the area below a curve, as opposed to a solid color.  If that's not possible, I could probably get by using a gradient, but I'm at a loss as to how I would accomplish either.

I considered using alpha to do this w/ some kind of background image, but due to the multiple canvas layers, I don't think it's feasible.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to get this implemented with jqPlot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly change colors in area charts using the options but you cannot use different colors under one series of data. Use a color theme before creating the chart object. like

```
seriesColors: [ "#eee", "#ccc", "#999"], in options string
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  Are there any graphing plugins that would support such a thing?

Comment: I'm not sure,but as a hack you can give the same series argument to draw for other 6 series so all together you have 7 series with rainbow colors and to make sure they do not overlap you can reduce the y values by one unit from each series when you go top to bottom of the graph.

Comment: Well, I'm actually mapping wavelengths of visible light(in nanometers), so I'm sure I could get really fancy with it and run across the whole color spectrum with 10 wavelengths per series, or something like that.  

I'll definitely give it a shot, thanks again.